# How to get cart object in my app js file

Tags: shopify

Hi I am working on shopify app. 
Using the script_tag I added custom.js for shopify store front end.
When look in view source I can see custom to js added successfully

Basically I need a **function or object** if we have in shopify that i can use in my custom.js file remember I am not talking about theme file that return me complete info of cart like how many product added etc because that particular object I need to send with my ajax request to php file 
Is there a way i can get cart detail in my app js file ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using (.js) file you cannot directly access cart object. Instead you can use (.js.liquid) file type to access cart object. Both (.js) and (.js.liqud) works similarly. But by using (.js.liquid) file format you will be able to access all shopify objects.

Code...

For (.js.liquid) file type
refer [cart object](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/cart) of shopify

But still if you want to access cart object in (.js) file you can access in json format by GET call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/cart.js',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(cart) {
          // whatever you want to do with the cart obj
        }
    });
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for reply 

yes we can do in this way but I am looking for a way if we have object .

Also is there a way we can check in js we are on cart page ? 

Because my js included on every page so this script will call on every page . Is there way in js we can restrict this cal only on cart page 

Or if we can include my js only for cart page ?

Comment: Yes, you can restrict cart.js call for only cart page in two different ways.
Firstly, Include your customized js only in cart.liquid file. Or, if you need to include your js in theme.liquid you can detect the cart page in your js using the following code.

if (window.location.href.indexOf("cart") != -1){
    //lines of code to be called in cart page
}

Comment: actually I can not make change in liquid file as i am working on shopify app

you have experience in shopify ?

Comment: Sir is there a way to connect other than stack overflow?

Comment: Yes you can mail me to radheshvayeda22@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143292/discussion-between-radhesh-vayeda-and-chauhan).

Comment: chat where sir ?

Answer (score 3):

Though Shopify offers a `.js.liquid` file format for the asset files, Shopify prevents accessing any information that might be dynamic (which would break the ability to cache the assets).  So while it may be intuitive to try and use `{{ cart | json }}` to dump the cart into the asset, carts are very dynamic and definitely not something you can liquid-dump into your code.

Fortunately, there are other ways to get this info!  If want to have the cart immediately on page load, you can use a snippet file to set a global javascript variable which would then be accessed by your asset file.  However, that would only get the cart as it existed at page load, and if you're using javascript to add/remove/modify items in the cart you'll want to be able to get the current cart when needed.

Which brings us to using AJAX to hit your store's `cart.js` endpoint.  If you're using a theme that has a full suite of Shopify helper functions, you might already have a function named `Shopify.getCart` - this is a function that grabs the current cart from the above endpoint, and if you pass a function as a parameter into this function your function be called with the current cart object once the asynchronous call is complete.

If your theme doesn't have a built-in getCart function, it's very easy to write your own.  For example, if you are already using jQuery in your theme, you could make a function like this:

```
function getCart(callback){
  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', callback);
}
```

To get the cart and do something with it, simply make a function that does stuff with the cart data and use that function as a parameter in your getCart function.

Example:

```
function updateTotalPriceOnTheScreen(cart){
//This example assumes that there's a DOM element on the page that has the ID cart-total-price
  document.getElementById('cart-total-price').innerHTML = Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, '${{ amount }}');
}

getCart(updateTotalPriceOnTheScreen);
```

Further, it's worth noting that Shopify's response object when you change or update the cart (through the `/cart/change.js` or `/cart.update.js` endpoints, respectively) will pass the updated cart object to any success function that's been supplied.  So you could, for example, re-use your update function:

```
function changeItem(line, quantity, success_callback, error_callback){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/cart/change.js',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{
      line:line,
      quantity:quantity
    },
    success:success_callback,
    error:error_callback
  })
}
//Test case: requires at least one item in the cart. Will update the quantity of line 1 to 50 units, then update the 'total price' element on the page
var line=1, qty=50;
changeItem(line, qty, updateTotalPriceOnTheScreen)
```

Comment: Hi Dave 
Thanks for reply I see in view source of cart page and I am unable to see Id = cart-total-price I mean Dom element 

How we can do this ? Or either we can ember Dom Element ?

Comment: HI Dave Is ther a way I can get products details in my app js file on the basis of product id 

Because I have product Id stored in my data base only 

My app js send request to my php controller and come back with products that i added 

Now I need title image of those product in js because result coming back in app js file 

Any suggestion ? 

I read about  Javascript buy sdk but to use this we need to generate tokem in shop admin we can do this as we are going to install this app on multiple store

Comment: Hi @Chauhan - Sorry for the wait, I don't always remember to swing by StackExchenge when things get busy.  The 'cart-total-price' was an example - every theme is different, so I have no way of knowing what your theme is using as a class or ID to identify the element that contains the cart price total - you would need to change that code to something that makes sense on your store.  Regarding getting products by ID instead of handle...

Comment: You can get products by ID through the admin if you're running with admin-level permissions... which the average shopper will not have.  I would strongly recommend adding product handle as a field to your database or whatever so that you can pass it along to the generated javascript.  However, if that's not an option, you can get a list of all products by making a GET request to `/products.json` and loop through all the results to get to the one you want.  I don't know of anything more direct, unfortunately